# What happens to a quantum harmonic oscillator at $T = 0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, temperature, harmonic-oscillator

Say I have two identical non-interacting particles of spin $\frac{1}{2}$ and masses $m$ in a harmonic potential with constant $k$.

What would be the average kinetic energy of the gas at $T=0$? What is the total energy?

**My attempt**

The particles are non-interacting and the energy is just $E = E_1 + E_2$. The system is necessarily in its GS, therefore the total energy must be $E_{T=0} = \hbar \omega$, where $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$.

For the kinetic energy (I think) I can use the fact that the GS is a minimum uncertainty solution, therefore we have

$$
\Delta x \Delta p = \frac{\hbar}{2}
$$

where $\Delta x^2 = <\psi_0|\hat{x}^2|\psi_0> = \frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}$. Therefore I get that

$$
<K> =2\cdot  \frac{\Delta p^2}{2m} = 2 \cdot\frac{1}{2m}\big(\frac{\hbar}{2 \Delta x}\big)^2 = \frac{\hbar \omega}{2}
$$

is it correct to use the uncertainty on $p$ to compute the kinetic energy? Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

The ground state is doubly occupied as you stated.

While your final result for kinetic energy is correct, using uncertainty principle in general does not give you the correct answer, because the value of an observable is not necessarily equal to its standard deviation. You could use your intuition that for a harmonic oscillator the kinetic and potential energies are on average equal (Virial theorem) or find $\langle p^2 \rangle$ directly using integration or ladder operators ($a,a^\dagger$).